# Updating records older than n minutes

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database with a datatime field called last_accessed and another field called stale.

How do I update the stale field for records older than say 5 minutes?

e.g.

This doesn't seem to work.

update mytable set stale=1 where (datetime('now') - last_accessed) > 300;

In fact
select datetime('now') - '2011-02-22 08:48:34';
returns 0.

How do I do arithmetic in sqlite3?

EDIT:
Since I'm converting last_accessed to a datetime and really it just needs to be a seconds field. Do you think I should convert that field to seconds field instead.  Then I won't need to do something like strftime('%s',time('now')) - strftime('%s',last_accessed)?

Edit2:
There is no difftime function as far as I can tell.  I discovered you have to use strftime('%s', datetime('now')) - ... format to make it work.  However, instead I've converted simply to an integer field where I'm storing time(NULL) directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
select datetime('now') - datetime('2011-02-22 08:48:34');
```

or something like that (see the [examples](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)).

Comment: That still doesn't work.  Have converted to a int field instead.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question in case others are wondering how to correctly do date/time arithmetic in sqlite.

The correct answer is:

update mytable set stale = 1 where strftime('%s', datetime('now')) - strftime('%s', last_accessed) > 300;

However, I don't actually need the datetime format in the table and have instead opted for a numeric field instead.  I'm not seeking any more answers to this question.

Thanks.

Comment: You should mark this answer as accepted. That will keep this question from showing up as an unanswered question.

Comment: I will be doing that as soon as stackoverflow allows.  They have a 2 day period for accepting an answer for your own questions.